# Contact Form 7 + Popup Maker не правильная работа

Tags: wordpress, popup, contact-form7

Всех, приветствую. Реализована связка Contact Form 7 + Popup Maker все работает корректно, кроме одного момента. В настройках Contact Form 7 после установки плагина Popup Maker появляется возможность указать действия после отправки формы, переадресовать на другой попап, так вот он переадресовывает в любом случае даже если форма не отправлена, это не доработка разработчиков? Или я чего то не понимаю? 
Вопрос: как сделать переадресацию на попап с благодарностью, только после успешной отправки сообщения?

Comment: очевидно, написать самому. Найдите того, кто напишет такой код

Comment: Реализовано через другую связку